# Angular Momentum or Gravitation question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

> Question: If the earth suddenly shrinks to $\frac{1}{64}$th of its original volume keeping mass same, the period of rotation of earth becomes $\frac{24}{x}$ hours, what is $x$?

So basically, why can’t we use the basic Keplers law $T^{2}$ is directly proportional to $R^{3}$

If we use Keplers law, it goes like:

1. $V = \frac{4}{3 \pi} R^{3}$
2. New volume is equal to $\frac{V}{64} = \frac{4}{3 \pi} R_{new}^{3}$
3. Dividing 1 and 2, we get $64 = \left( \frac{R}{R_{new}} \right)^{3}$ so $R_{new} = \frac{R}{4}$
4. We use $T^{2}$ is directly proportional to $R^{3}$
5. So $\frac{24}{ \left( New ~ time ~ period \right)^{2}} = \left( \frac{R}{\frac{R}{4}} \right)^{3}$
6. So $\frac{24}{\left( New ~ time ~ period \right)^{2}} = 64$
7. $\frac{24}{New ~ time ~ period} = 8$
8. $New ~ time ~ period = 3$
9. Therefore according to the question, $\frac{24}{x} = 3$ so $x$ is $8$

HOWEVER THE ANSWER IS 16
SOMEONE PLEASE HELP

Comment: Hi Red. This will likely be closed as a homework-like question, but: Kepler's laws are about the motion of an object (typically a planet) around another object (typically a star). But you are applying it to Earth's rotation about *itself*.

Comment: I kinda understand, but if you could elaborate further it’ll be helpful

Comment: Try conservation of angular momentum of a rigid body.

Answer (score 1):

This is about Earth rotating on itself, i.e. definition of day. By invoking Kepler's 3rd Law you are talking about month or year. i.e. orbits. You are simply looking at the wrong equation. The answer key is correct.